# Javascript: onclick and some drag thing had a baby?

Tags: javascript, events, onclick

Here's the page I'm working on: http://kylemorgan49.com/sb/gridster/

When you hover over a box the background changes color (from css :hover)
and when you click javascript changes the color to red.
So after playing with this, you could imagine that this could be used as a drawing app. So how would I make it change color as you click and drag across multiple boxes? So that you don't have to click each and every box. Thanks! Oh and you can view code by right clicking and click view source (fyi)

Comment: A plainer title might get you more help.

Comment: Can you please consider adding some code directly into your question. The page you link to could dissappear in time making it hard for people who will have similar issues in the future use this question to help solve their problem.

Plus it will make it much easier for people to answer your question - which will make them more likely to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Bind a mousedown event on your grid to set a "clicking" flag
2. Bind a mouseenter event on each grid square. If the mouse enters and "clicking" is true, colour it
3. Bind a mouseup event on your grid to clear the "clicking" flag

e.g

```
var clicking = false;

// the user is holding the mouse button down, so we want to draw as they move over squares
$('#grid').mousedown(function(e) {
    clicking = true;

// the user has released the mouse, we don't want to draw anymore
}).mouseup(function(e) {
    clicking = false;
});

// when the user hovers a box, check if the user is holding down the mouse and drawing
$('#grid .box').mouseenter(function(e) {
    if (clicking) {
        $(this).addClass('colour');
    }
});
```

Comment: This looks like something I want however I don't know JS very well so could you comment it out and tell me what parts I need to change? Also, you can use jQuery if it's easier.

Comment: Added a few comments. It's already using jQuery. You'll need to replace the jQuery selectors with the id/class names of your real elements. If you have questions about a specific portion of the code, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You could keep track of the mouse button with mousedown and mouseup.  Set a variable, like `var mouseButton = true;` on mousedown.  You'll also want mouseover events for your boxes.  When mouseover is triggered, check the value of mouseButton.  If it's true, change the color of the box.